# Connection between ER model and domain/design class diagrams

Tags: entity-relationship, class-diagram

Currently, I'm working on design class model and domain class model. 
I have entity class `Account` and class `Member` .

 I know that class diagrams and ER models can differ from each other.
However, Should I in the ER model include such entities as `Account` and `Member` , or can I combine them into `Account` entity?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it seems to me that `Member` belongs to the domain and matters to the business users. It should therefore also be `«Entity»`. But your question seems not really about entities, but more about tables:

- `Members` and `Accounts` are in your UML distinct classes, since they have different structural and behavioral characteristics. But also in an ER model they would be different entities, as their attributes may vary independently:
- Considering that `Account` and `Member` are associated one to one in your model, you could consider to store both in a combo-table. That’s an implementation decision about the tables. But it does not really change the entity semantics: a member is still something different from an account.
- While you can do this combo-table shortcut, you should ask yourself if this is a good idea in view of the principle of separation of concerns. Keeping them separate will ease your ORM mapping and facilitate maintenance.
- If the association of `Member` with `Account` would be one-to-many or many-to-many, it would be another story: if you’d combine them into a single table, your relational model would no longer be normalised, and this has many inconveniences.